# Как создать .iso-образ из нескольких .bin-файлов?

Tags: c, ассемблер, iso-образ

Внимание! Возможна агрессия от глупости вопроса, просьба отнестись с пониманием!

Решил сделать helloworld-ОС по одному туториалу из интернета. Скомпилировал 2 файла на FASM.

boot.asm:
https://pastebin.com/Cm7gwzrC

kernel.asm:
https://pastebin.com/i8RAhys5

Скомпилированные файлы в формате .bin. В туториале их загружают на флэшку через специальную программу. А можно ли как-то эти 2 файла связать и "положить" в .iso, чтобы можно было использовать, например, в Virtual Box?

И ещё, можно ли, например, kernel.asm переписать на C, используя ассемблерные вставки, скомпилировать в .bin и использовать? Пытался такое провернут в Visual Studio, полетели ошибки с непонятными жалобами на ассемблерный синтаксис. Извиняюсь если  сказал что-то совсем уж глупое, просто в гугле уж слишком мало информации по этой теме.

Comment: Попробуйте 
Ultra ISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultra ISO, приложение создания образов диска. Вы можете сделать загрузочным образ, редактировать и многое другое

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать